# SPRESENSE Wi-Fi Add-onボード iS110Bの使い方

Tags: spresense

iS110Bを挿入し、MQTTで信号を送受信したいと思っています。
これにつき、セットアップや実装に役立つサイトがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jittermaster/GS2200-WiFi/blob/master/Documents/GS2200_MQTT-001.pdf

こういったものがあるようです。
ちなみに、他のサイトは自分も探してみたのですが、現時点でなさそうです。

それと、もともと質問されていた、ハンドサインAIの情報は、ここで見つけました。
https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/sony-spresense-ai-hand-sign-recognition

Comment: ありがとうございました。非常に参考になりました。